# How can I remove dot from a nested object in logstash

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

We have a complex object with nested fields that the field names can be dynamic and contains dot.When I try to ingest data to elasticsearch it gives me the following error

```
Object mapping for [x] tried to parse field [x.y] as object, but found a concrete value
```

One record can have key/values like `a.b.c:4` and in other record it can have `a.b:3`.  We don't have control of the source of coming data so the only option can be changing the object in logstash. Here is an example of coming object:

```
{
    "result": "https://www.yahoo.com",
    "tags": {
      "url": "https://www.yahoo.com",
      "projectName": "monitor",
      "host": "ttt",
      "dd": 12345,
      "vv": "kk"
    },
    "timestamp": 1586599441000,
    "runId": 12345,
    "performance": {
      "x.y.z": 31307

    },
    "channel": "clientperf",
    "asset": {
      "a.b.c": 5,
     "a.b":4
    }
  }
```

as you see values inside asset and performance  has dot. The fields on the roots(like runId, performance and ...) are fine. How can I resolve this either with replacing the dot in logstash or anything that doesn't give me error. I'm aware of `de_dot` plugin but to use it we need to specifically tell what are the name of nested fields while we cannot enforce the naming for the coming records.I also know that we probably can achieve this with `ruby` plugin but I have zero knowledge of ruby. Any help can be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could use `Hash#deep_transform_keys` from `ActiveSupport`:

```
class Hash
  def deep_transform_keys(&block)
    result = {}
    each do |key, value|
      result[yield(key)] = value.is_a?(Hash) ? value.deep_transform_keys(&block) : value
    end
    result
  end
end
```

`puts hash.deep_transform_keys { |key| key.to_s.gsub(".", "" ) }`

Comment: is `ActiveSupport` part of rails? how can I use it in logstash?